# bottom nav bar fragment multiple times

Tags: java, android

home fragment always on screen.i cant solve it.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.homeFragment)

} 

/*@Override
protected void onStart() {
    if (currentUser==null){
        Intent welcomeIntent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,WelcomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(welcomeIntent);
        finish();
    }
    super.onStart();
}*/

homeFragment homeFragment = new homeFragment();
notificationFragment notificationFragment = new notificationFragment();
todolistFragment todolistFragment = new todolistFragment();
profileFragment profileFragment = new profileFragment();

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.homeFragment:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, homeFragment).commit();
            return true;
        case R.id.notificationFragment:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, notificationFragment).commit();
            return true;
        case R.id.todolistFragment:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, todolistFragment).commit();
            return true;
        case R.id.profileFragment:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, profileFragment).commit();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

on home fragment it doubles.background texts are doesn't disappear.how can i solve it.what is the problem.i am using android studio with java

Comment: post the `xml` code as well. How do you know that it doubles?

Comment: added the xml code. i see 2 page together.

Answer (score 0):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx6rv.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHR7j.png)

these are the screen shots.main text view always appears